# EXTRA_DIST not considered on VPATH Build

Tags: c, build, autotools, autoconf, automake

I have a project with the following directory structure (simplified):

```
configure.ac
Makefile.am
samples
src/Makefile.am
tests/openssh_keys
tests/Makefile.am
```

The top-level Makefile.am has the following content:

```
EXTRA_DIST = $(srcdir)/tests/openssh_keys \
             $(srcdir)/samples
SUBDIRS = src . tests
```

The directory 'openssh_keys' in 'tests' contains data that is needed for the unit tests. When Im creating a package with 'make dist' all files mentioned in EXTRA_DIST are properly included in the package. Im getting into trouble when using 'make distcheck' as this creates a VPATH Build. Unfortunately the files mentioned in EXTRA_DIST are not copied leading to an error when the test-cases are run.

Anyone has a proper solution for including the files mentioned in EXTRA_DIST even in a VPATH Build?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you don't need to specify `$(srcdir)` in `EXTRA_DIST`.

Comment: tried without $(srcdir) but still the same problem

Comment: Add tests/openssh_keys to DIST_SUBDIRS? I had a small laugh at "no dirty hacks or workarounds" -- for one; not sure if you would consider this a dirty hack, and number two, I kind of consider autotools a dirty hack ;)

Comment: make distcheck
...
test -d "pam_openssh_x509-0.1" || mkdir "pam_openssh_x509-0.1"
 (cd tests/openssh_keys && make  top_distdir=../../pam_openssh_x509-0.1 distdir=../../pam_openssh_x509-0.1/tests/openssh_keys \
     am__remove_distdir=: am__skip_length_check=: am__skip_mode_fix=: distdir)
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sebastian/development/pam_openssh_x509/tests/openssh_keys'...
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'distdir'.  Stop.
Makefile:587: recipe for target 'dist' failed
make: *** [dist] Error 2

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the error you're receiving as you didn't report it, but I found [your repository](https://github.com/flix-/pam_openssh_x509) and taken a look (I would suggest you to take a look at what you're writing in `configure.ac` because it could be simplified, but that's a different topic.)

From what I can see in the code, the problem is that you're not actually providing the test binary with a path where to find the files, and it instead looks for it in CWD-relative fashion. But `make distcheck` (and many distributions) use out-of-tree builds in which `$(srcdir)` is not `.`, and thus it fails.

`EXTRA_DIST` will not help you: that only tells automake to copy the files in the tarball, but not out of `$(srcdir)` ever. You should instead provide the test code itself a way to know where `$(srcdir)` dir is. Since you're not using a test driver or script, the least-changes suggestion I'd have would be

```
pam_openssh_x509_check_CPPFLAGS = -DKEYSDIR="\"$(srcdir)/openssh_keys\""
```

and then change the test source to

```
    char *directory = KEYSDIR;
    char *oneliner = KEYSDIR "/ssh_rsa.txt";
```

so that it would find them in the relative path (`../../tests/openssh_keys`).

Comment: cant check the solution right now but will on the weekend. as bounty will expire soon i'll reward you in advance. thanks for making work and searching the repository and checking the code :)